# i am trying to extract the specific table from the website but i am having problem doing it

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

i am trying to extract the table of qualifications in scope but i am having hard time doing it since its my first time. can anyone please help me
url of the website i am scraping : https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/31102

```
enter code here
import re
import csv
import time
from pathlib import Path

import details as details
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as bs4
import os
import copy

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" - incognito")
option.add_argument("headless")
exec_path = '/Users/Downloads/MUR_scraping-master/Libraries/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=exec_path, options=option)

# read the url from each file into a list
course_links_file_path = Path(os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/'))
course_links_file_path = course_links_file_path.__str__() + '/links.txt'
course_links_file = open(course_links_file_path, 'r')

# the csv file we'll be saving the courses to
csv_file_path = Path(os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/'))
csv_file = csv_file_path.__str__() + '/Reading_undergraduate.csv'

for each_url in course_links_file:
# print(each_url)
try:
    browser.get(each_url)
except:
    print(each_url)
    pass
pure_url = each_url.strip()
each_url = browser.page_source
delay_ = 15
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(each_url, 'lxml')

desc_div = soup.find('div', class_='t-content t-state-active')
if desc_div:
    desc_list = []
    desc_p_list = desc_div.find_all(class_='display-row')
    if desc_p_list:
        for p in desc_p_list:
            desc_list.append(p.get_text())
        desc_list = ' '.join(desc_list)
        #print(desc_list)

table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

Comment: Which table do you want to extract?  your desc_div  section is ok. Its work well with extracted information.

Comment: i want to extract the table in scope section. the table thats named qualification

Answer (score 0):

Not my best code but the following scraps the table into a 2D array. My solution is a bit sloppy but I hope this is something you can work with.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import bs4 as bs4

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--headless")
exec_path = "TODO: Add your path"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=exec_path, options=option)

browser.get("https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/31102")

# open the scope tab
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a#detailsScopeTab').click()
# wait for the table to load
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="ScopeQualification"]//div[@class="t-pagesize-wrapper"]')))

# click on the button to have all rows at once
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="ScopeQualification"]//div[@class="t-pagesize-wrapper"]/a[last()]').click()


# wait for the table loads the new data
class element_css_class_flashed(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, css_class):
        self.locator = locator
        self.css_class = css_class
        self.was_on = False

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
        if self.css_class in element.get_attribute("class"):
            self.was_on = True
        elif self.was_on:
            return element
        else:
            return False

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 3)
    element = wait.until(element_css_class_flashed(
        (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="ScopeQualification"]//div[@class="t-status"]/a'), 
        "t-loading"))
except:
    # most likely the loading was too fast to detect
    pass

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('div#ScopeQualification table')
all_rows = table.find_all('tr')
header_row = all_rows[0]
rows = all_rows[1:-1]

data = [[col.text for col in header_row.find_all('th')]]
for row in rows:
    data_row = []
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        data_row.append(col.text)
    data.append(data_row)

print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! its helpful i will try resolve the printing

Comment: Hi! sorry to bother you but i want code to read the links.txt where there are all the links of courses so that i can extract all the links scope, is there anyway its possible?